# setState after props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Form Component for user create a post. When user submit will call API Post and show Alert Component (AC), AC will disappear after 2s. I use redux to hold error global state and AC will render based error state

> error state is: error = { code: 201, text: 'CREATE SUCCESS' }, error state default: error = {} ).

But when I create post two time (create a post => AC show and disappear after 2s => then continue create a post => AC no show) AC don't show like I want. I want every time I create post AC will show and then disappear. Thank for your help and sorry for my bad English.

I know when I create Post at second. `nextProps.error.code = 201` and `nextState.error.code = 201`, so it return null. I dont know how to fix that.

Alert Component look like - I use with Reactstrap:

```
class Alarm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      alarm: this.props.alarm, // props from redux 
      isOpen: false,
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextProps.alarm.code !== nextState.alarm.code) {
      return {
        alarm: nextProps.alarm,
        isOpen: true,
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isOpen: false } ),2000);
  }

  render() {
    const { alarm, isOpen } = this.state;
    const color = alarm.isError ? 'danger' : 'success';
    return (
      <div className="s-stream-alert">
        <div className="s-stream-alert__wrapper">
          <Alert color={color} isOpen={isOpen}>
            { alarm && alarm.code !== 0 && alarm.code }
          </Alert>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  alarm: state.alarmReducer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Alarm);
```

Main Component look like:

```
<div>
   <FormComponent />
   <Aler />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that when you create post the second time `nextProps.error.code = 201` and `nextState.error.code = 201`, so it returns null. Along with storing the error code, you can store a uniqueID for each time a error is fired. Eg. a randomly generated numeric/string ID like 'e5nxgbjbm' or something of that sort. You can then check if IDs are equal and return accordingly in getDerivedStateFromProps. This would solve the issue.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

However, I also want to point out the line in the constructor where you set state  `alarm: this.props.alarm`. This is not necessary  and you can do all the checks with this.props.alarm. You do not need this as state. You can just use props everywhere. There is no need to set a new state property as alarm as you are not updating it in any way. The component will be re-rendered either way when props changes.